# Portable way of depending on the generator program in a Makefile pattern rule

Tags: makefile

I have a `src/apps/myapp/myapp` program that I am building as part of automake rules, which is working correctly.

I am then using this in a Makefile rule to generate a HTML file, e.g.:

```
.src.html: src/apps/myapp/myapp
    src/apps/myapp/myapp --html $< > /tmp/generated && \
        mv /tmp/generated $@

html: data/src/example.html src/apps/myapp/myapp
```

This works in that it builds `src/apps/myapp/myapp` and generates `data/src/example.html` from `data/src/example.src` when running:

```
make html
```

When `data/src/example.src` changes, it correctly regenerates `data/src/example.html`.

The problem is that if `src/apps/myapp/myapp` changes, it does not regenerate `data/src/example.html`. Also, the `src/apps/myapp/myapp` program is build after the HTML files (i.e. it is only using the `html` target dependencies and not the `.src.html` rule dependencies).

**UPDATE:**

With GNU Make, I can change:

```
.src.html: src/apps/myapp/myapp
```

to:

```
%.html : %.src src/apps/myapp/myapp
```

This works as intended, but relies on a GNU make extension. Can I do this in a portable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suffix rules do not support extra prerequisites.  According to the POSIX standard, they are ignored.

Of course, you can declare any target/prerequisite relationship at any time, they do not have to be declared within the rule containing the recipe.

You don't show any list of HTML files, but if you have one in a variable (say, `$(HTMLFILES)`) then you can just declare:

```
$(HTMLFILES): src/apps/myapp/myapp
```

and that will work (and be portable).